# When Dynamically setting text of a textview, throws an error that the TextView can not be Empty?

Tags: android, variables, kotlin

I am building a simple application where in I am trying to display the 'name' and the 'email' address of the user who just logged in. 
I am getting the value from Intent Extra. 
When I log the intent extras in the console,it does displays. However, it only works when I log it. 
When I try to assign it to set the text of the text view, it throws the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: faculty_nav_header_name must not be null.

Here is the code for it:
This is where I am trying access the member variables outside the object.

```js
    fun setupUI(){
        faculty_home_dateStamp.text = getDate_of_month()
        faculty_home_dayStamp.text = getDay_of_week()
        val previousIntentValueName = intent.getCharSequenceExtra(LOGIN_TO_FACULTY_INTENT_USER_NAME)
       val previousIntentValueEmail = intent.getCharSequenceExtra(LOGIN_TO_FACULTY_INTENT_USER_EMAIL)
       println(TAG + "name : " + previousIntentValueName + ",  Email : "+ previousIntentValueEmail )
      faculty_nav_header_name.text = previousIntentValueName
      faculty_nav_header_email.text = previousIntentValueEmail
    }
```

And here is my nav_header code snippet:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/sicsrYellow"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faculty_nav_header_name"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text=" "
        tools:text="Farhana Desai" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faculty_nav_header_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text=" "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faculty_nav_header_name"
        tools:text="farhana.desai@sicsr.ac.in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/faculty_nav_header_setting"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/sicsrYellow"
        android:onClick="nav_header_setting_clicked"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faculty_nav_header_email"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_001_settings"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_setting_image_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/faculty_nav_header_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/sicsrYellow"
        android:onClick="nav_header_logout_clicked"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/faculty_nav_header_email" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please have a look and see if you find anything to make this work. 
Note: I am using this nav header for all my avtivities, can that possibly cause this to not work?

Comment: Do you call the method `storeFacultyData` before you get the value ?!

Comment: This function is called at the time of login, and I am using it's value to display name of and email of the user in the next activity.

Comment: did you check that `mUserUId` is not null by that time ?! i guess its null so it prevent the variables to be filled

Comment: It is not, otherwise it would have loged me a messsage.

Comment: The problem is with `faculty_nav_header_name`. It can't find that view. Are you sure you have such a WIDGET in your current view ?!?!?

Comment: I am sure it is there, and value if I print it , it prints fine, but when I assign it to faculty_nav_header_name, it says it can't be null

Comment: Please post your complete xml

Comment: added changes, please check.

Comment: Where are `faculty_home_dateStamp` and `faculty_home_dayStamp` ?!
You are loading another view!!! that is why it does not find your `faculty_nav_header_name`. are you showing a fragment in an activity?

Comment: I am trying to set the value of textview on the navigation drawer header, and facutly_home_dayStamp and dateStamp are on the activity main screen.

Comment: Try doing this:  `activity?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.faculty_nav_header_name)!!.text = previousIntentValueName`

Comment: Didnt work, :(. Throws a NullPointerException.